# Lua programming - os.execute() is not working in Windows

Tags: windows, eclipse, lua, command-prompt

I'm creating a function in pure-Lua to scan the files from a directory and put they on a another file.

The command I tryed was:

```
os.execute( "dir /B C:\\Users\\Fernando\\workspace\\Organizator2\\s1 > 
C:\\Users\\Fernando\\workspace\\Organizator2\\temp.txt" )
```

but... dont works! I did many tests with others simpler commands, like "start notepad" or "mkdir C:\test", and they dont worked too! The worse part is that I tryed this same commands directly in the Prompt, and there is all correct.

I tryed use tooo the io.popen(), but it the system returned "illegal operation" for any command i passed (even a empty string!).

here is the all code:

```
function ScanDirectory(source, str) 
    local str = str or "temp.txt" 
    os.execute("dir /B "..source.." > "..str) 
    directory = io.open(str,"r") 
    return directory 
end 

--  main script 

do 
    local source = "C:\\Users\\Fernando\\workspace\\Organizator2\\s1" 
    local directory  = ScanDirectory(source, "C:\\Users\\Fernando\ 
\workspace\\Organizator2\\temp.txt") 
end
```

I'm using windows 7 and the Luaforwindows, 5.1, and the LuaEclipse

Have someone ever seen a problem like this?

Comment: Trick: either use forward slashes, working well in Windows as well, or long strings notation: [[C:\Users\Fernado\etc.]]. Both are nicer (and easier to type / use) than these doubled backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested your code on my computer and it works correct (with my directories, of course). Maybe you are not getting the expected result because your `directory` string is broken with an newline char, resulting in:

```
dir /B C:\Users\Fernando\workspace\Organizator2\s1 > C:\Users\Fernando\
workspace\Organizator2\temp.txt
```

The correct should be:

```
dir /B C:\Users\Fernando\workspace\Organizator2\s1 > C:\Users\Fernando\workspace\Organizator2\temp.txt
```

Please try changing the do end to:

```
local source = "C:\\Users\\Fernando\\workspace\\Organizator2\\s1" 
local directory  = ScanDirectory(source, "C:\\Users\\Fernando\\workspace\\Organizator2\\temp.txt")
```

Comment: Actually, it was broken only here in SO, not in my program. but.. it magically works! What kind of witchcraft is that?????? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please try it with this syntax:

`os.execute [["dir /B C:\Users\Fernando\workspace\Organizator2\s1 > 
C:\Users\Fernando\workspace\Organizator2\temp.txt"]]`

Please note that the backslash (`\`) is not a special character in this case.
(Lua uses cstrings internally, sometimes it leads to some weird and amazing results :P)

Comment: Do you need the double quotes? Without the double quotes, this exactly what the OP had, though it is easier to the eyes. Also, see http://www.lua.org/about.html#name

Comment: Thanks for responsing but it not solved... the same problem continues, i have already tried use the [[ ]] notation, but i didnt know that i must use the "" too.. good to know :]

Answer (score 1):

Most of the commands you listed appear to be shell commands that only work within a command prompt.  Try running cmd.exe directly to see if you get a prompt, and if so, you can try passing commands to cmd.exe via the /c option.  You could also try notepad without the start to see if that runs.

Comment: Thanks for responsing, but it didnt work either... via cmd all the commands works well, with /c or without it, but via the function, none. if i were in linux I would think that was a permission problems, but i'm in a windows as admin, so i dont know what may be!

Comment: From your comment, I'm not sure you understand the /c part.  There is no dir.exe in windows that I know of, so "dir.exe c:\" will fail for a command not found.  But "cmd.exe /c dir c:\" will work because dir is a shell command in windows.  I don't have a Lua environment up to test, but if it's like any of the other windows programming I've done, you need to run executables, not shell commands.

Comment: You can also test in Lua by running "cmd.exe" as an executable from Lua to see if that runs, or just "notepad.exe" rather than "start notepad.exe".

Answer (score 1):

```
os.execute('cmd.exe /c dir /B C:\\> C:\\test.txt')
```

That works. Useing Linux-style commands in win is a bad idea at all =)