# Lua os.execute() does not work

Tags: eclipse, lua, command-prompt

I'm having a problem with the Lua os.execute() command.

I just want to echo a word and write it into a file, like `echo 'aword' > C:\folder\tempworkspace\foo` to try the os.execute() command. The direcory C:\folder\tempworkspace exists, "foo" is the name of the file I want the command to create and fill with "aword".
Later, when this works, I'd like to call R, using `R -q -e "rbinom(1000,1,0.7)" > C:\folder\tempworkspace\foo`.

I've already tried all the advice provided in
[Lua programming - os.execute() is not working in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007266/lua-programming-os-execute-is-not-working-in-windows) and [Why won't applications in Program Files run using os.execute in lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587788/why-wont-applications-in-program-files-run-using-os-execute-in-lua)
but my problem seems to be a different one, maybe not even in the syntax, but somewhere else?

When I type those command directly in the Command Prompt, they work. I use Windows 7 Professional as an administrator, and Lua 5.1.4 with Eclipse.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
os.execute("echo 'hehe' > C:\folder\tempworkspace\foo")
os.execute [["echo 'hehe' > C:\folder\tempworkspace\foo"]]
os.execute [["echo 'hehe' > 'C:\folder\tempworkspace\foo'"]]
os.execute [[echo 'hehe' > C:\folder\tempworkspace\foo]]
os.execute [[echo 'hehe' > C:\\folder\\tempworkspace\\foo]]
os.execute[[cmd.exe /c echo 'hehe' > C:\folder\tempworkspace\foo]]
os.execute("cmd.exe /c echo 'hehe' > C:\\folder\\tempworkspace\\foo")
os.execute("cmd.exe /c echo 'hehe' > 'C:\\folder\\tempworkspace\\foo'")
```

I'd be very grateful for any suggestions to improve my code. (Note: I'm writing to a file, because I want to use the output later in lua. Another way of doing this, using io.popen() has been suggested somewhere, but it is said to be platform dependent, anyway my Lua crashes when I try to use `x = io.popen("R -q -e 'rnorm(10)'")`).

Edit, after first answer:

Your sendMsg function somehow also does not work on my computer, and I don't get any error, I really wonder what's the problem. For pcall, am I doing this right? As the line `print(err)` does not print anything I wonder if I am doing correctly.

```
function sendMsg(cmd, msg, fpath)
  local output = cmd.. " ".. msg.. " > ".. fpath
  print(output)
  os.execute(output)
end
function sendMsgArgs()
  sendMsg("echo", "huhu", "C:\\merret\\tempworkspace\\foo");
end
err = pcall(sendMsgArgs) 
if err == true then
  print("THIS WORKED")
else
  print("THIS DID NOT WORK")
  print(err)
end
```

Edit: This was actually a Eclipse/editor issue. So I wanted to add some tags, such as lua-eclipse, but I can't.

Comment: From the first list of 8 os.execute(...) commands you tried, actually the versions at lines 2, 4, 5, 6 and 7 work on my computer! Are you sure you have write access to the directory?

Comment: That's interesting. When I execute the same commands from the normal command prompt, they work. Also I am administrator. So I think I have write access. But could I be wrong? Could the write access be different when the commands are executed via Lua? How can I find out/change this? Do you know this? That would be so helpful!

Comment: pcall() returns 2 values, a bool and an error string if an error occurred. so change your 2nd snippet to `local result, error = pcall(sendMsgArgs)` and `print(error)` if `result` is false. this will probably tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this snippet of code works on my Win7 box:

```
function sendMsg(cmd, msg, fpath)
    local output = cmd.. " ".. msg.. " > ".. fpath
    print(output)
    os.execute(output)
end

sendMsg("echo", "hehe", "C:\\path\\to\\foo");
```

you need to make sure the file exists before you attempt to write to it. are you running this from the lua interpreter? do you get any error messages back when it fails to do the write?

alternatively - you can just use io.open() and write that way. wrapping this in a function and calling it using pcall() may give you more information if you have some sort of windows issue opening/reading to that location.

```
local fout = io.open("C:\\path\\to\\foo", "w+")
fout:write("hehe")
fout:close()
```

an example using pcall:

```
local result, error = pcall(sendMsg, "echo", "huhu", "C:\\merret\\tempworkspace\\foo")
if result == false then
    print(error)
else
    print("success!")
end
```

Comment: THanks for your fast answer!

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! `fout = io.open(...)` works, but later I will have to run R commands (e.g. `R -q -e "rbinom(1000,1,0.7)" > C:\folder\tempworkspace\foo`) from the command line and print their results to the file, so this will not help me, if I don't get this wrong. Your sendMsg function somehow also does not work on my computer, or maybe I'm not doing it correctly, I will post my code beneath my initial question (this comment is not large enough, and it's not really an answer... I'm still a Stackoverflow newbie too).

Answer (score 1):

it's been a while, but finally (thanks to a colleague), I figured out that the problem was not the Lua code, but actually executing Lua from Eclipse (I'm using the Lua Eclipse plugin).

Executing a lua file with the code

```
x = os.execute('R -q -e rnorm(10) > C:/folder/something/foo') 
print(x)
```

from the command prompt or using Crimson Editor (see below), it worked perfectly, and returned status code 0 (instead of -1 when executing from Eclipse).

Thanks a lot to all helpers anyway!
That Thing

PS: For anyone who is interested, I'm using Lua as part of the TerraME environment, http://www.terrame.org/doku.php. There is also a description there how to use Crimson Editor.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I run the exact same code in another ide and it works fine. If I run the exact same command line in a command prompt it works, but if I run in an eclipse project it doesn't work!!! ;/ Did you ever make any headway?

Answer (score 0):

If the path you're trying to write to contains a space, it must be surrounded by double quotes under Windows; single quotes will throw an error.

As such, the following works fine for me:

```
os.execute([[ echo test > "C:\\Program Files\\xyz.txt" ]])
```

Comment: But should fail for most users of Win7 or later with the default ACLs in place for attempting to write on `\Program Files`. Nested in `os.execute` like this, the failure will likely be hard to diagnose.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try with file paths not containing any space, to avoid that problem...