# os.execute() with command line options

Tags: windows, lua

**The Question:**  How do I execute an OS Command with three command line options in Lua ?

I have a device connected to my PC.  (Windows 7, USB cables, typical corporate)

The software which controls the device is located here...

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerUSB\
```

The name of the executable file (aka "*Program*") is...

```
pwrusbcmd
```

That program wants three single digit parameters either 1 or 0, separated by spaces

I opened a command prompt box, switched to that directory, and tested all 8 cases. All worked fine.

I then switched to another subdirectory, and tried this command...

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerUSB\pwrusbcmd" 1 1 1
```

That also worked fine.

So I figured that the Lua command to execute that command would be either...

```
 os.execute("C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerUSB\pwrusbcmd 1 1 1 ")
```

or

```
 os.execute("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PowerUSB\\pwrusbcmd 1 1 1")
```

Lua runs each, with no complaints, ***BUT,*** no action occurs on the device.

So I tried to alter the construction of the command itself, with the `".."` connecting the two segments of the total string, like this...

```
 os.execute("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PowerUSB\\pwrusbcmd".." 1 1 1 ")
```

Still no action.

I looked here on StackOverflow, and found

- [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270346/lua-os-execute-does-not-work)
- and [THIS ONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007266/lua-programming-os-execute-is-not-working-in-windows)
- and [THIS ONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587788/why-wont-applications-in-program-files-run-using-os-execute-in-lua)
- and [THIS ONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263291/lua-os-execute-with-command-line-arguments)

I am in sympathy with each person who wrote those questions. Much like user ID *thatthing*, I also tried..

- square brackets
- quote marks (`"`)
- single and double and triple backslashes
- front slash and s (`/s`)

So far, I can't find a single syntax construction that works.

The only "fix" (misnomer if there ever was one) I could concoct on my own is to write eight different MS-DOS bat files, and give them unique names. This renders the machine de facto unusable.

**How do I get Lua to execute this command ???**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerUSB\pwrusbcmd 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add the double quotes around the command name, the easiest way is to use single quoted strings:

```
os.execute('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PowerUSB\\pwrusbcmd" 1 1 1')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `os.execute([["C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerUSB\pwrusbcmd" 1 1 1 ]])`

I believe your problem is the spaces in the file path.

I know you say you used square brackets, but I can't see what combination of them you have used. This works for me.

Comment: Okay, so Yu Hao used a single quote to wrap the whole contents, while you used two square brackets.  Is this documented in http://www.lua.org or somewhere else ?  Thanks if you can point me to it.